# Creating a UIImage outside the main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, uikit, uiimage

I am creating a UIImage in a background thread using the code below, and then setting this image as the image of my view on the main thread. Once in a while, I get a bad access error. I am wondering if I should not be creating a UIImage in a background thread. Any thoughts?

```
CGImageRef imageRef =
    CGImageCreate(serverInit.rfbWidth,serverInit.rfbHeight,bitsPerComponent,bitsPerPixel,bytesPerRow,colorSpaceRef,bitmapInfo,provider,NULL,NO,renderingIntent);

    screenImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CFRelease(imageRef);

    [view performSelector:@selector(replaceImage:) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:screenImage waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: if don't perform a selector replaceImage, does it crash? I think your screenImage released before selector perform on other thread.

Comment: I havent tried it without the selector - this error occurs rarely, and I cant really test the app for extended periods fo time without this selector. As for the release, I thought I could do it right after creating the UIImage with the imageref. Is that not the case?

Comment: if rarely, then screenImage relases before replaceImage selector

Answer (score 0):

Try use this, it prevent screenImage to be released

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(serverInit.rfbWidth,serverInit.rfbHeight,bitsPerComponent,bitsPerPixel,bytesPerRow,colorSpaceRef,bitmapInfo,provider,NULL,NO,renderingIntent);
    screenImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CFRelease(imageRef);
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [view replaceImage:screenImage];
});
```

Comment: Thanks I've changed my code accordingly - will observer over the next few days and if I don't get the crash again, will mark this as the correct answer. To reiterate my original question though, is it ok to have the line:     screenImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
 in the background thread?

Comment: why not? do you use it in other place?